# Getting Null Value From One Action Method to Another Action Method In Same Controller In MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application.

I am trying To Pass cityid to **_CreateCityWiseArea** action method from **CityWiseAreaList** in same controller.

But data doesn't pass properly.

`_CreateCityWiseArea` action method getting null value.

Please check below code...

---

This Is My Area Controller:

```
public ActionResult CityWiseAreaList(int cityid)
{
    if (cityid == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var data = db.Areas.Where(x => x.CityID == cityid).ToList();

    //TempData["ID"] = cityid;

    RedirectToAction("_CreateCityWiseArea", new RouteValueDictionary(
   new { controller = "Area", action = "_CreateCityWiseArea", id = cityid }));
    return View(data);
}

public ActionResult _CreateCityWiseArea(int? id)
{
    // var cityid = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ID"]);
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var Name = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityID == id).Select(x => x.CityName).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewBag.message = Name;

    return View();
}
//Add Area to Corresponding city 
// POST: Area/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _CreateCityWiseArea(Area area)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Areas.Add(area);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("CityWiseAreaList");
    }
    ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "CityName", area.CityID);
    return PartialView(" ~/Views/Area/_CreateCityWiseArea.cshtml", area);
}
```

I Use `Redirectoaction`, `tempdata` method to pass Value but both time null value is coming.

Comment: You're not **returning** the RedirectToAction.

Comment: In your first action result `CityWiseAreaList` you arent actually returning the `RedirectToAction`. Unless some code is missing?

Comment: if i write return to RedirectionToAction then at return view getting unreachable code error.Actually i want to display Area Name Corresponding to City And at time i want to pass **cityid** to **_CreateCityWiseArea** Action Method.@Valeklosse,@J.Steen

Comment: @Ash that sounds like you want to use a partial view, which is called from your main view. i.e. `@Html.Partial("_CreateCityWiseArea", Model.Id)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass id from `CityWiseAreaList` to `_CreateCityWiseArea` this should be simple, since it's in the same `Controller` you don't need to add the `RouteValueDictionary` but it's your choice anyway. The below should work, that's the way I'll go:

```
 return RedirectToAction("_CreateCityWiseArea", new { id = cityid });
```

Comment: without using RouteValueDictionary it works but now i m getting another problem.The problem is ,i am getting cityid to GET **_CreateCityWiseArea** action method but this cityid is not coming To POST **_CreateCityWiseArea** action method. so due to this in my database only AreaName is Storing not cityid.i want both cityid and AreaName Should be Save into databse.plz check my code and correct it if is not correct.